# xsl:value-of select= ... <url type="html">

Tags: xml, xslt

my XML has this

```
<mailing>
<send-date><![CDATA[2016-05-03 07:08:05]]></send-date>
<subject><![CDATA[My sbjekt]]></subject>
<url type="text"><![CDATA[http://mytextlink]]></url>
<url type="html"><![CDATA[http://myhtmllink]]></url>
<url type="pdf"><![CDATA[http://mypdflink]]></url>
</mailing>
```

I only want to select the

```
<url type="html"><![CDATA[http://myhtmllink]]></url>
```

What ist the right XSLT-Syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the syntax you are looking for is this...

```
'<xsl:value-of select="url[@type='html']" />`
```

So, this selects the `url` element, with the condition that its `type` attribute equals "html".

This assumes you are currently positioned on the `mailing` element. If not, you can do this, which will work whatever your context

```
'<xsl:value-of select="/mailing/url[@type='html']" />`
```